# Is there any way to deploy EAR without bindings to Websphere 7

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, deployment, websphere-7

I'm using Maven to build EAR files. I need to deploy them to WAS 7 without IBM RAD. It seems that there is no way to deploy using maven plugins like Cargo. Because they don't support this version of WAS.

Also I tried to use Jython scripts, but I can't deploy EAR without ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml. When I use WAS Console there is an option to merge bindings during application update, but it seems that scripts don't provide this option.

So, is what is the best option to deploy EAR pragmatically?

Comment: Can you deploy your ear/war manually? In that case possibly WebSphere creates these files during deployment (see .../profiles/base/installedApps/xxx/xxx_war.ear/xxx.war/WEB-INF/...). Then copy these files, and package these files into your .ear. This may not work with WS7, but that's the way I always did it using WS6.

Comment: The problem is that I want to deploy automatically using Maven. Moreover I can create these files by myself. But it seems to me a wrong decision creating EAR with these files. I just want to do the same thing without WAS Console.

Answer (score 0):

I used a mix between websphere ant tasks and maven ant plugin

check this 
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc%2Fpublic_html%2Fapi%2Fcom%2Fibm%2Fwebsphere%2Fant%2Ftasks%2FInstallApplication.html

Comment: This method from WAS 6.1 seems a bit complicated and obsolete, but anyway thank you for reply.